# How to retrieve all companies data in Intrinio based on tags like apturnover, 52_week_high, capex, ceo, adress etc in csv column? in intrinio

Tags: api, csv

> I want specific tags in CSV column with a list of all companies. I downloaded all companies details but there are only four columns in that CSV file. I want to pass all companies details as identifier and items as some specific tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intrinio has limit 150 for data tag and identifier combination. so you can use Intrinio Excel Add-in and write which data tags you want in next column. 
write macros like =intrinioDataPoint(A2, $B$1) for first data tags, =intrinioDataPoint(A2, $C$1) for second and so on. if you want more combination then checkout intrinio tutorial on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j39b7pTWMAw&t=337s).

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the Data Point endpoint and specify the tickers and items you want to download ([example](https://intrinio.com/api-explorer?formula=data_point&values=eyJpZGVudGlmaWVyIjoiQUFQTCxNU0ZULEdFLE5GTFgiLCJpdGVtIjoibmFtZSx0aWNrZXIsY2VvLGFwdHVybm92ZXIifQ%3D%3D)). This is limited to 150 combinations of tickers/items however. They also have an Excel add-in with a data point function that you can use on every row of a spreadsheet. Beyond that, you can contact their support and request a custom data dump.